# по событию ng-click сделать имитацию клика на tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, angularjs

Имеется header.php в котором 5 табов.

```
<div class="tabs">

<input id="tab0" type="radio" name="tabs" checked ng- 
click="ShowCont('Global')">
<label for="tab0" title="">Create Company</label>

<input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" ng-click="ShowCont('List')">
<label for="tab1" title="">List Company</label>

<input id="tab3"  ng-style="checked" type="radio" name="tabs"  ng- 
click="ShowCont('Company')">
<label for="tab3" title="">Company Options</label>
<input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs" ng-click="ShowCont('Show')">
<label for="tab4" title="">Black List</label>

<input id="tab5" type="radio" name="tabs"  ng-click="ShowCont('integration')">
<label for="tab5" title="">integration</label>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<button ng-click="listNameCompany(nameCompanys.nameCompany)" class="btn 
btn-info">Edit</button></div>
```

есть кнопка по событию которого я хотел бы перейти с  таб с Create Company на таб Company Options.

есть файл js в котором я ловлю событие клика.

```
 $scope.listNameCompany = function (namecompany) {

   Хотел бы тут сделать имитацию клика на Company Options.

    };
```

Могу ли я сделать имитацию клика, при котором я перейду на другой таб?

Comment: Покажите рабочий пример кода, а не нарезки из него. Иначе может получиться как в притче о слоне и мудрецах.

Comment: Что конкретно не понятно, есть header. Мне по событию клика кнопки сделать активным другой таб. Представь что это весь код) как быть в данной ситуации?

Comment: Я вот что думаю https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD

Comment: Рад за тебя, замечаю от тебя комментарии вечно не по теме.

Comment: Судя по огромному количеству ответов на ваш вопрос - не я один считаю, что приведенной в вопросе информации недостаточно для ответа. Не хотите улучшать вопрос - ваше право.

Comment: Сегодня переделаю.

Answer (score -1):

Решил вопрос в такой форме. ng-style

```
<input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked ng-click="ShowCont('Global')">
 <label ng-style="Show == 'Global'?{'background':'blue','color':'white'}: 
 {'background':'green','color':'white'}" for="tab1" title="">Global Options</label>


  $scope.ShowCont = function (text) {
    $scope.Show = text;

   }
```

С помощью ng-click="ShowCont('Global')" я перехожу на другую вкладку и тем самым срабатывает условие для ng-style="Show == 'Global'